# Jquery HTML Traversal in Below code

Tags: jquery, html

```
<div class="main">
<button class="btnClick" type="button"> </button>
<button class="btnClick" type="button"> </button>
<div class="child">
<p> ** Some child Text ** </p>
<textarea id="edit" class="hidden"></textarea>  //class hidden == Display:none
</div>
</div>

<div class="main">
<button class="btnClick" type="button"> </button>
<button class="btnClick" type="button"> </button>
<div class="child">
<p> ** Some child Text ** </p>
<textarea id="edit" class="hidden"></textarea>  //class hidden == Display:none
</div>
</div>
```

Am trying to implement the edit section with the above code. The above `<div>` is generated dynamically and when user click the button i need to hide the `<p> "** Some child Text ** " and make the Textarea visible` for that particular Div and copy the

section to Textarea

I tried  On Button Click

```
$(this).closest('#edit').removeClass("hidden");
```

but it didn't worked and with the other code every time only first  textarea is visible irrespective of which  button i click

What am looking for is on the first button click the particular `<div> textarea class hidden to be removed and copy the<p> text to Textarea on that particula <div>`

What is the best way to do this. and i can add any new class and make code generic. Your ideas !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should remove the id from the textarea to avoid having multiple id's which are the same.

This function does what you need.

```
$(document).on('click', '.btnClick', function(){
    //cache the child div block (everything you want is in here)
    child = $(this).next('.child');

    //hide the p tag
    child.find('p').hide();

    //this copies the p tag in
    child.find('textarea').val( child.find('p').html() ); 

    //this shows the textarea
    child.find('textarea').show();
});
```

here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6wAUK/

Comment: Fiddle looks great !! how do i navigate to div if i have 2 buttons on first button click

Comment: I don't follow what you mean?

Comment: updated code in my question another button added and i want the event to happen on first button click

Comment: The easiest way would be to assign another class to the first button & run the jQuery against that. Otherwise you could do $('.main').find('.btnClick').first().click( function() { ... } ); You could copy the function I'm here.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(document).on('click', '.btnClick', function(){
    var div = $(this).next()
    div.find('p').hide();
    div.find('textarea').show();
})
```

Comment: Thanks! some minor change in my HMTL.Updated Code

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(this).parent("div").find('#edit').removeClass("hidden");
```